# Corda on Kubernetes

Tags: corda

I want to deploy my corda nodes on a kubernetes cluster.
My architecture looks pretty much the same [as described here](https://www.corda.net/blog/cordanetes-combining-corda-and-kubernetes/).

Actually all my nodes start up and my backend (Spring boot) connects without a problem.
If I try to start a transaction it's recognised and passed to the other node(s).
Just the connection back to the backend fails.  If I connect to the dockerized Nodes via a locally started backend, which isn't dockerized, it works perfectly fine.
So I assume it has something to do with the communication between the nodes and the backend.
I am 99% sure that my config is right. Any ideas?

Running latest corda version (4.3) and latest docker version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that the latest corda version is 4.5 so perhaps an upgrade could help with the issue.

There could be something going wrong in your config, but since it wasn't shared I can link you to this blog post which has a good explanation and a code example: https://medium.com/corda/combining-corda-business-and-docker-networks-112c9667c831

There's also the official corda repo which does have an example, but is slightly outdated : https://github.com/corda/corda-docker/blob/master/docker-compose.yml